# Adding Compass to Rotate MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, compass-geolocation

I'm using the code of MapsDemo Sample to draw a Map that rotates according to the compass, but  enableCompass is not working to show the compass on MapView. I tried to add this compass http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Compass.html. But when I add it to my application, the arrow appears frozen. Any ideas?

Comment: Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74740478/851699

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that it will only work on actual hardware.

Put this line in `onCreate`:

```
    MyLocationOverlay me = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(me);
```

Then add this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    me.enableCompass();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    me.disableCompass();
}
```

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) that enables the compass on `MyLocationOverlay` that definitely works, though you will need to substitute in your own `android:apiKey` value.